# VBScript simulate as you type

Tags: html, windows, dom, vbscript

I am about so automate an exchange rate lookup with **VBScript**.
The webpage I use is **http://www.oanda.com/lang/de/currency/converter/**.
I am accessing and manipulating the DOM via

```
Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Navigate "http://www.oanda.com/lang/de/currency/converter/"
objIE.Document.getElementById("end_date_input").Value = "10.10.2015"
```

The website works unfortunately with **as-you-type** (there is no submit button, just live update). So if you directly enter the values for date in DOM, the webpage will not take the input for calculation. I don't know exactly which **event** triggers the as-you-type function (onchange? keystrokes?) and I certainly don't know how to trigger it without sendkey or some similar workaround. **How can I trigger the calculation?**

Thank you very much, ideas in any direction are appreciated.

Details:

*How the page is meant to be used:*

You type in a new value for home quote currency and with every keystroke, the value for base currency is updated. there is no button to start calculation.

*How I use the page:*

I fill in the values with the above mentioned code. That does not trigger the calculation, unfortunetly, meaning that the value for base currency does not change even if i insert a new value for quote currency.
Unless i use the SendKey function of the windowsshell (which I would like to avoid), I can not trigger the calculation.

Comment: you could try another route, prefill the form values over a GET request, as such --> [currency/converter?quote_currency_0=USD&base_currency=EUR&quote_amount=777&end_date=2015-12-14](http://www.oanda.com/currency/converter?quote_currency_0=USD&base_currency=EUR&quote_amount=777&end_date=2015-12-14)

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea! Would have never thought of that, i guess, thank you so much, i will try as soon as i find the time.

Comment: Little error to correct:   currency/converter? **quote_currency=USD** &base_currency=EUR&quote_amount=777&end_‌​date=2015-12-14